# comparing model accuracy means and standard deviations with different parameters

Tags: r, modeling, boosting, optimization

Trying to fit model to stock data (stochastic).
Sample, model (gbm), predict out of sample.

```
a=createDataPartition(sac$rst, p = p_part) 
aa=sac[a[[1]],] 
ab=sac[-a[[1]],]
modelo=gbm( formula = f1
              ,data = aa[c(6:19,21)]
              ,distribution = 'adaboost'
              ,n.trees = teste$trees[l]
              ,interaction.depth = teste$interDepth[l]
              ,n.minobsinnode =teste$minObs[l]
              ,shrinkage = teste$shrinkage[l]
              ,cv.folds=10
              ,keep.data = T, verbose = F
              ,n.cores = 5)
        #all trees
        prev=predict(modelo,newdata=ab[,6:19],n.trees =teste$trees[l],type='response')
```

The same parameter configuration runs several times, producing different results. The most accurate model should be better. Below the mean and standard deviation of the runs.

```
trees interDepth minObs shrinkage   xAcu       sdAcu
 2000          2      6     0.010 0.5570 0.014142136
 2000          5      1     0.005 0.5735 0.013435029
 5000          2      6     0.005 0.5630 0.005656854
 2000          5      1     0.010 0.5835 0.031819805
 5000          3     10     0.001 0.5610 0.025455844
```

Is the model with best mean better, even having the largest standard deviation?
Is there a metric to discount standard deviation from mean to choose the better model?